# How to set ASP.NET Core 2 to fix arrow functions in bundleconfig.json

Tags: javascript, .net-core, bundle, babeljs, bundling-and-minification

I am using a lot of arrow functions in my java script such as

```
$(document).ready(()=> {
    var n = 0;
    n++;
    console.log("n is " + n);
});
```

in asp.net core 2 project I have bundleconfig.json as following:

```
{
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/site.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/js/site.js"
    ],
    // Optionally specify minification options
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true,
      "renameLocals": true
    },
    // Optionally generate .map file
    "sourceMap": false
  }
```

the minified output would be like this :

```
$(document).ready(()=>{var n=0;n++;console.log("we are ready"+n)});
```

which dose not work on IE, I need to convert the arrow function to a proper function closure something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){var n=0;n++;console.log("we are ready"+n)});
```

how could I do this?

Comment: Are you sure? Do you know, that "this" has difference context in arrow function comparing again classic functions. Because of that I am not entirely sure that this translation is safe.

Comment: You just need to add a transpiler to generate ES5 code.

Comment: Yes you are right, but can you please tell me how to integrate babel with .net core 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need some polyfill transpiler for that. Like TypeScript or Babel.
Maybe [this](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-arrow-functions/) can help you.

For integration with ASP.NET Core [this link](https://medium.com/@vinjenks/webpack-2-babel-6-es6-in-asp-net-core-1-1-from-scratch-ed7a6a289ba7) or [this one](https://github.com/kriasoft/aspnet-starter-kit) may help you. If not your best option is to find some template on GitHub. Although it may be hard, since most templates you can find connects ASP.NET Core with Angular or React.

Comment: Thanks, Yet that does not answer the question, How could I implement it in .Net Core 2 ?

Comment: @EhsanZargarErshadi Tried to edit my answer. To help you beyond that, I do not have enough knowledge. Good luck.

Comment: The example you provided on the second link is for dot net core 1, not 2

Comment: It should be similar.